# EF get list of parent entities that have list of child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have to next 2 entities in my project

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductImages = new HashSet<ProductImage>();
        this.ProductParams = new HashSet<ProductParam>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    public int CodeProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string SeriaNumber { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool AvailableInStock { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual CodeProductType CodeProductType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductParam> ProductParams { get; set; }

}

public class ProductParam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CodeProductParamId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual CodeProductParam CodeProductParam { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to get list of Products which has list of specified parameters

```
var prodParamCritria = new List<ProductParam>() 
{
new ProductParam(){CodeProductParamId =1, Value="Black" }, 
new ProductParam(){CodeProductParamId =2, Value="Steal"}
};
```

in sql I can do it by using EXISTS clause twise

```
SELECT *
FROM   Products p
WHERE  EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM   ProductParams pp
           WHERE  pp.ProductId = p.ID
                  AND (pp.CodeProductParamId = 1 AND pp.[Value] = N'Black')
       )
       AND EXISTS (
               SELECT *
               FROM   ProductParams pp
               WHERE  pp.ProductId = p.ID
                      AND pp.CodeProductParamId = 2
                      AND pp.[Value] = N'Steal'
           )
```

How can i get same result by EF methods or linq

Answer (score 1):

I suppose something like that should work

```
db.Product.Where(x => x.ProductParams.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CodeProductParamId == 1) != null && x.ProductParams.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CodeProductParamId == 2) != null).ToList();
```

or better

```
db.Product.Where(x => x.ProductParams.Any(y => y.CodeProductParamId == 1) && x.ProductParams.Any(y => y.CodeProductParamId == 2)).ToList();
```

Ok, if you need to make query on parameters in list prodParamCriteria it will look like this:

```
db.Product.Where(x => prodParamCritria.All(c=> x.ProductParams.Any(p=>p.CodeProductParamId == c.CodeProductParamId && p.Value== c.Value))).ToList();
```

I forgot that complex types cannot be used in query database, so i propose you to convert your prodParamCriteria to dictionary and use it in query

```
Dictionary<int, string> dctParams = prodParamCritria.ToDictionary(x => x.CodeProductParamId , y=>y.Value);
db.Product.Where(x => dctParams.All(c => x.ProductParams.Any(p=> p.CodeProductParamId == c.Key && p.Value== c.Value))).ToList();
```

Comment: i cant use this because you are hardcored filter options in lambda, I need to filder prdoucts by productparams which exists in prodParamCritria variable

Comment: I added query, that select data based on parameters specified in list prodParamCriteria.

Comment: last example give an error **Unable to create a constant value of type 'ProductParam'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

Comment: your code is incorrec, it gives error.  x.ProductParams is ICollection i can't write  x.ProductParams.CodeProductParamId

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var products= db.Products.Where(p=>p.ProductParams.Any(pp=>pp.CodeProductParamId == 1 && pp.Value == "Black") && 
                                     p.ProductParams.Any(pp=>pp.CodeProductParamId == 2 && pp.Value == "Steal"));
```

### Update

The problem in work with that list of `ProductParam` to use it as a filter is that EF doesn't know how to translate a `PodructParam` object to SQL, that's way if you execute a query like this:

```
 var products2 = db.Products.Where(p => prodParamCritria.All(pp => p.ProductParams.Any(e => pp.CodeProductParamId == e.CodeProductParamId && pp.Value == e.Value)));
```

You will get an `NotSupportedException` as you comment  in the answer of @BostjanKodre.

I have a solution for you but probably you will not like it. To resolve that issue you could call the `ToList` method before call the `Where`. This way you will bring all products to memory and you would work with Linq to Object instead Linq to Entities, but this is extremely inefficient because you are filtering in memory and not in DB.

```
var products3 = db.Products.ToList().Where(p => prodParamCritria.All(pp => p.ProductParams.Any(e => pp.CodeProductParamId == e.CodeProductParamId && pp.Value == e.Value)));
```

If you want filter by one criteria then this could be more simple and you are going to be able filtering using a list of a particular primitive type. If you, for example, want to filter the products only by `CodeProductParamId`, then you could do this:

```
  var ids = new List<int> {1, 2};
  var products = db.Products.Where(p => ids.All(i=>p.ProductParams.Any(pp=>pp.CodeProductParamId==i))).ToList();
```

This is because you are working with a primitive type and not with a custom object.

Comment: I need to filter products by data existing in prodParamCritria variable

Comment: Product table is very large to bring it to app server and then filter data in memory, but thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

another variation:

```
IEnumerable<Int32> lis = prodParamCritria.Select(x => x.CodeProductParamId).ToList();
var q = Products.Select(
        x => new { 
            p = x,
            cs = x.ProductParams.Where(y => lis.Contains(y.Id))
        }
    ).Where(y => y.cs.Count() == lis.Count()).
    ToList();
```

with a named class like (or maybe without, but not in linqpad)

```
public class daoClass {
    public Product p {get; set;}
    public Int32 cs {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<Int32> lis = prodParamCritria.Select(x => x.CodeProductParamId).ToList();
var q = Products.Select(
        x => new daoClass { 
            p = x,
            cs = x.ProductParams.Where(y => lis.Contains(y.Id))
        }
    ).Where(y => y.cs.Count() == lis.Count()).
    SelectMany(y => y.p).
    ToList();
```

Comment: and what about  Value="Black" and  Value="Steal" ?

Comment: you probably can use SqlFunctions to aggregate fields and test the aggregate.